# Solr 8.7 configset empty when uploaded with authentication

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solrconfig, solr8

We have enabled authentication in Solr 8.7 and now I want to upload a configset and thereby create a collection based on this configset.
I have followed the below steps:

1. **create config zip**
   (cd /disk/configsets/my-collection/conf && zip -r - *) > my-collection.zip
   The zip file rightly contains all configurations as expected with top level as solrconfig.xml
2. **upload configset to zookeeper**
   curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --user userSolr:pwdSolr --data-binary @my-collection.zip "http://host:port/solr/admin/configs?action=UPLOAD&name=my-collection"
3. **create collection**
   curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --user userSolr:pwdSolr "http://host:port/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=my-collection&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1&createNodeSet=localhost:8081_solr&collection.configName=my-collection"

I can see the configset listed in Solr UI as well as the created collection.
However, when I click on files section of collection, its empty. This collection has no configs **which means the configset is uploaded empty**.

What am I missing?